# Creating dynamic webapp in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have created a dynamic web application project in eclipse. I am able to display hello world. Now when I tried loading owl file I am getting error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/semanticweb/owlapi/apibinding/OWLManager

I just copied the jar to my lib folder. `owlapi-api-5.1.0.jar javax-inject.jar owlapi-apibinding-5.1.4.jar`. Please tell me what i am missing. Even the pom.xml file is not there in my project. I couldn't able to add maven dependencies. I don't know why? Please tell me how to add the depenency too.

Comment: What "lib" folder did you copy them into?

Comment: **/home/gayathri/eclipse-workspace/Newwebapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib** this lib folder